# I want my users to go to a thank you page after submitting their form. There's a slight issue though

Tags: forms, http, redirect, post, action

So like the title says, I want the user to be redirected to a thank you page.

The issue is I need to post the users data to a CRM called Granot. So currently I have the form action="https://lead.hellomoving.com/LEADSGWHTTP.lidgw?&API_ID=E432CD67C51E"

After submitting the form it goes to a blank page with some text on top explaining if there are any issues. Obviously, I would like my user to go to a nice Thank You page. The Granot website has some documentation if it helps at all.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VMpPFi4c4EhQUg9qab4tPkypgnUQF4U7L8Y-HU8I-R0/preview

In the table, there is a field name for redirurl which is used to redirect a user to a nice thank you page, but doesn't provide any instructions.

```
<form name="redirurl" method="POST" action="https://lead.hellomoving.com/LEADSGWHTTP.lidgw?&API_ID=E432CD67C51E">
      <div id="form_cotent">
        <div class="regForm">

          <div id="step_1">
            <div align="center" class="tab">

              <h3 align="center">Compare Rates and Save Money!</h3>
              <h2 align="center">About Your Move</h2>

              <input placeholder="From Zipcode" oninput="this.className = ''" name="ozip">

              <input placeholder="To Zipcode" oninput="this.className = ''" name="dzip">

              <input placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" oninput="this.className = ''" name="movedte">

              <select name="movesize">
                <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Size of your Move</option>
                <option value="Partial Home" >Partial Home</option>
                <option value="Studio" >Studio</option>
                <option value="1 Bedroom" >1 Bedroom</option>
                <option value="2 bedrooms" >2 bedrooms</option>
                <option value="3 bedrooms" >3 bedrooms</option>
                <option value="4 bedrooms" >4 bedrooms</option>
                <option value="More than 4 bedrooms" >More than 4 bedrooms</option>
                <option value="Office" >Office</option>
              </select><br>


            </div>

            <div align="center" class="">
              <button id="step1_fwd" class="btn bttn1" type="button">
                <span class="text">Start Your Quote</span>


              </button>
              <!--<button id="step1_fwd" class="btn btn-primary bttn1" type="button">Start Your Quote</button>-->
            </div>
          </div>
          <!---- Step 2 --->
          <div id="step_2" class="step_2" style="display: none;">
            <div align="center" class="tab">
              <h2>Step 2</h2>
              <h3>Contact Info</h3>

              <input placeholder="First name" oninput="this.className = ''" name="firstname">

              <input placeholder="Last Name" oninput="this.className = ''" name="lastname">

              <input placeholder="E-mail" oninput="this.className = ''" name="email">

              <input placeholder="Phone" oninput="this.className = ''" name="phone1">
            </div>

            <div align="center">

              <button type="button" class="prevBtn" id="step2-bck">
                <span class="txt">Back</span>
              </button>

              <div class="subBtn">
                <button id="step2_fwd" class="btn bttn1" type="button">
                  <span class="">Next</span>
                </button>
                <!--<button id="step1_fwd" class="btn btn-primary bttn1" type="button">Start Your Quote</button>-->
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>


          <div id="step_3" class="step_3" style="display: none;">

            <div align="center" class="tab">
              <h3>Any additional details you would like to share about your move?</h3>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Additional information..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="notes">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="auto" name="redirurl">Submit</button>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: redirect action should not be put to a [post]form

Comment: I think you have 2 ways: a. Guess what `redirurl` accept and try. b. Send the form POST request in Ajax and implement the thank-you page redirection yourself.